# wkWebView troubles in iOS 9: missing long tap, cannot select text properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, wkwebview

I am experiencing a couple of strange wkWebView behaviours on iOS 9, and I believe that these two issues are somehow connected...

- 1) Text selection is not working in `wkWebView`. As a test environment, I am loading an HTML file into `wkWebView`. After successfully loading, I'm breaking text into columns using `webkitColumnWidth`. After doing this, I can see that some parts of the texts cannot be selected using a long tap. For example in one of the paragraphs (`<p>`), part of the text could be selected, but another part of the text just doesn't react to a long tap. At the same time, I am able to normally extend my selection to the text area where long tap is not functioning properly. Why is this happening? Is any way to select any text with a long tap using `webkitColumnWidth` at the same time?
- 2) UIMenuController is not initiated on the first try. I'm loading HTML into `WKWebView` and manually selecting some text with a long tap. After doing this, I expect the built-in menu to appear, but it doesn't... It appears only after single-tapping a second time on the text that is already selected. My question is: How do I force the menu to appear every time I select the text with a long tap?

Here are my code snippets:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
   NSString *javascript =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"var meta = document.createElement('meta');meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=%f, height=%f, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);document.addEventListener(\"selectionchange\", function(){window.location  = 'ios:';}, false);",rect.size.width,rect.size.height];
   WKUserScript*  userscr = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource: javascript injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
   [contentController addUserScript:userscr];

   WKWebViewConfiguration* config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
   config.userContentController = contentController;
   WKWebView* webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect configuration:config];
   webView.navigationDelegate = self;

   …

   NSString *htmlStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                    error:nil];
   NSURL* baseURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:htmlPath];
   [webView loadHTMLString:ch.html baseURL:baseURL];
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView ​*)wView didFinishNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *​)navigation{
   NSString * insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.webkitColumnWidth = '%fpx';document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.height = '%fpx';document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.width = '%fpx';document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.marginRight = '10px';document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.marginLeft = '10px';document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.webkitColumnGap='0px';",self.view.frame.size.width/2-20,self.viewWV.frame.size.height,self.view.frame.size.width];

   [wView evaluateJavaScript:[NSString stringWithFormat:insertRule1 completionHandler:nil];   
}
```

Comment: have you reached any solution? I'm facing same problem!